# <Select> with onChange working only once, and setting values with getElementsByName

Tags: javascript, select, onchange, getelementbyid

I have various forms on a page, and a PHP-generated select on the top of the page.

What I want to do is:

- The user selects an option from the form.
- The value of the option is put into all of the inputs with a specific name.
- The user can select another option, and the value of that option would replace the old value of the input.

The code I have so far (that doesn't work):
It doesn't work as in the onChange only fires *the first time* you select an option, and the values of the inputs aren't updated to the chosen option's value.

The select: (It can have more or less than three options, depending on the user.)

```
<select name="example" onchange="setexample()" id="exampleID">
<option value="1">Default Example</option>
<option value="12">User-created Example #2</option>
<option value="8">User-created Example #1</option>
</select>
```

This is part of one of the forms around the page:

```
<form action="[URL]" method="get">
<input type="hidden" name="exampleform" id="example1" value="">
// Other inputs //
</form>
```

JavaScript:

```
<script>
function setexample(){
setexample = document.getElementById("exampleID").options[document.getElementById("exampleID").selectedIndex].value;
document.getElementsByName("exampleform").value = setexample;
}
</script>
```

I don't want to use jQuery. This is just JavaScript.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `getElementsByName()` method returns a list of elements, so you can't just directly set the `value` property that belongs to the individual elements in the list. You need to loop through the list (it's an HTMLCollection but for this purpose you can treat it like an array):

```
var els = document.getElementsByName("exampleform");
for(var i = 0; i < els.length; i++)
    els[i].value = setexample;
```

For the rest, see RobG's answer.

Comment: Thank you for the help. That works perfectly, and I had no idea that it was an HTMLCollection/array. It seems logical, though.

Answer (score 1):

In your code:

```
> function setexample(){
>   setexample = document...
```

The assignment to setexample overwrites the existing value (which is the function setexample). Declare the variable inside the function:

```
    var setexample = document...
```

For the rest, see nnnnnn's answer.

Comment: The circle is now complete. +1.

Answer (score 0):

You have these issues:

1. You're overwriting the name of your function and should use a local variable of a different name.
2. You're reference a single element form getElementsByName when it returns an array.

Try this:

```
<script>
function setexample(){
    var item = document.getElementById("exampleID"); 
    var val = item.options[item.selectedIndex].value;
    var list = document.getElementsByName("exampleform");
    for (var i = 0; i < list.lenth; i++) {
        list[i].value = val;
    }
}
</script>
```